# Are right -continuous functions on $[a,b]$ integrable?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose that $f:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a right-continuous function, that is, $f(x+)=f(x)$ for all $x \in [a,b)$. Are these functions $L^1$?

I think that right-continuous functions would be (locally) bounded so that the answer would be affirmative, but I cannot prove this easily.
Maybe enumerating the rationals will allow me to construct an exotic counterexample? I'm not sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is horribly false.  For instance, on $[-1,0]$, you could have $f(x)=1/x$ (with $f(0)$ defined however you want).  More generally, $f(x)$ could blow up as fast as you want as $x$ approaches some $c\in [a,b]$ from below, while being continuous above $c$.

Answer (score 2):

$f(x)=\frac  1{b-x}$ for $x<b$ and $f(b)=0$ is a counterexample.

However, if you assume that $f$ is bounded then we can show that it is  continuous almost everywhere and this makes $f$ Riemann and Lebesgue integrable.

Comment: "...if you assume that $f$ is bounded..."; came here to post this, and here it already is.  Ha,  +1